# magento2, category products position in catalog product list widget

Tags: magento2.2

I have added positions to the products in category in the backend.

[image]

This position is working in Category page in Frontend. But this position of product is not working in Product list widget inside a CMS page.

[image]

How can this value of position be used in Product list widget?

This is value is stored in this table in magento2 database.
[image]

Comment: If you product list widget then from which category you will pull the positions because one product could be assigned to multiple categories?

Comment: Conditions
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Category  is   17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I var_dump() my grid Product object, I found some data related to "cat_index_position" in it. This is actually the piece of data I had to use to sort my product list.
[image]

[image]

So I run two for each loop to sort again my product array and I get my products positioned according to the value given to on Category settings in Magento admin.

```
$items          = $block->getProductCollection()->getItems();
var_dump($items);exit;

$CatIndexPosition= array();
$positioned_items= array();
foreach ($items as $_item): 
    $CatIndexPosition[$_item->getId()]=$_item->getCatIndexPosition();
endforeach ;
//print_r($CatIndexPosition);echo'<br>';//exit;
$zeroadjust = max(array_keys($CatIndexPosition))+1;
//echo $zeroadjust;exit;
foreach ($CatIndexPosition as $key => $value): 
    if($value=='0'){
        $positioned_items[$zeroadjust]=$items[$key];
        $zeroadjust++;
    }
    else{
        $positioned_items[$value]=$items[$key];
    }
endforeach ;
ksort($positioned_items);
```

Now in our loop i replaced $items variable with $positioned_items which i have created.

```
<?php foreach ($positioned_items as $_item): ?>
    <div class="col-sm-6 <?php if($iterator==0){?>p-l<?php }?>">
        <div class="img-box">
```

Comment: nice answer but i have add code in 2.3.5 version and it is not working it any other change need?

Comment: I have no idae about it, but you can check the code inside this file in magento 2.3 and then do adjustments.